# Google Play Android Developer API > androidpublisher.inapppurchases.get

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, in-app-billing

EDIT: I think the scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher but now I get invalid value.

The app I use is the sample app included in the billing api named trivaldriving modifying the pay load to 123 and package to com.appspot

SKU I see in my wallet is inapp:com.appspot:gas

(right click on image and open in new tab)

[image: console]
[image: console]

I think the token field is wrong and it is not the payload but something else?

Comment: Try toggling the `use OAuth` button and see if that changes the scope.

Comment: When I use the button, the scope its empty by default and I must add something to be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) by token they mean sales token that only the android device can get `infiniteGasPurchase.getToken()` and it is not the payload token or access token or refresh token.

2) products is just in my case `gas` not the sku `com.appspot.gas`

3) scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher

And yes this made me frustrated haha :)

Comment: infiniteGasPurchase.getToken(), this is how you get the token that can be used to check purchase. Yes, i'm frustrated, too...